# Как взять значение из файла и присвоить его переменной

Tags: c++

Ребят, смотрите, мне нужно взять посчитать площадь и периметр, после этого записать результат в файл, как-то изменить последнюю его строчку и уже из нового файла забрать переменную a и с ней по новой посчитать площадь и периметр (для последней строчки) и само собой вывести результат.
Вот что пока есть.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// начало объявления класса
class Square // имя класса
{
    static const unsigned int ROWS = 3;

    int mas[ROWS];
    int mas1[ROWS];
    int mas2[ROWS];
    int mas3[ROWS];

public: // спецификатор доступа
    int S, P; // объявление переменных для расчёта площади и периметра
    string line;

    int calc_s(int a) // функция (метод класса) которая расчитывает площадь
    {
        S = a * a;
        return S;
    }

    int calc_p(int a) // функция (метод класса) которая расчитывает периметр
    {
        P = 4 * a;
        return P;
    }

    void enter_S(int b) // функция (метод класса) которая выводит ранее посчитанную площадь
    {
        cout << "Площадь квадрата: " << S << endl;
    }

    void enter_P(int b) // функция (метод класса) которая выводит ранее посчитанный периметр
    {
        cout << "Периметр квадрата: " << P << endl;
    }

    void output(int mas[ROWS],int mas1[ROWS],int mas2[ROWS],int mas3[ROWS])
    {
        int a = 2; // переменная для объекта A
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            ofstream f("input.txt", ios::app);
            mas[i] = i + 1;
            f << endl <<mas[i] << "\t";
            mas1[i] = i + a;
            f << mas1[i] << "\t";
            mas2[i] = calc_s(i + a);
            f << mas2[i] << "\t";
            mas3[i] = calc_p(i + a);
            f << mas3[i] << "\t";
            cout << mas[i] << "\t" << mas1[i] << "\t" << mas2[i] << "\t" << mas3[i] << "\t" << endl;
            f.close();
        }
    }

    void input()
    {
        int mas25[50];
        int n = 0;
        int x = 0;

        ifstream file;
        file.open("input2.txt", ios::in);
        cout << "Файл после изменений";
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            
        }
        
        else
        {
            cout << "Файл не был изменен" << endl;
        }
        
        file.close();     // закрываем файл
    }

}; // конец объявления класса Class


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    int a = 2; // переменная для объекта A

    static const unsigned int ROWS = 3;
    int mas[ROWS];
    int mas1[ROWS];
    int mas2[ROWS];
    int mas3[ROWS];

    Square objclass; // объявление объекта A
    objclass.calc_s(a); // вызов функции класса calc_s (тут у нас считается площадь)
    objclass.calc_p(a); // вызов функции класса calc_p (тут у нас считается периметр)

    cout << "Объект А" << endl;
    objclass.enter_S(objclass.calc_s(a)); // вызов функции класса enter_s (выводит посчитанную площадь на экран) ДЛЯ ОБЪЕКТА А
    objclass.enter_P(objclass.calc_p(a)); // вызов функции класса enter_s (выводит посчитанный периметр на экран) ДЛЯ ОБЪЕКТА А
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    

    cout << "ID   " << "Переменная " << "Площадь  " "Периметр" << endl;
    cout << "========================================" << endl;
    objclass.output(mas, mas1, mas2, mas3);
    cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    objclass.input();
    cout << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то многовато мейнов, не должно такое компилится.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Ойй,я случайно дважды скопировал,сейчас поправлю

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков  поправил